# Android Facebook exception

Tags: android, facebook, exception

Google Play reports exception. Some people complain in comments as well.

I do not get such exception myself.

What should I wrap with try/catch to handle it?

Or how do I fix it? 
Or how do I get full stack trace?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.roolez.tinshot/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3027)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3070)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4508)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$KatanaProxyAuthHandler.onActivityResult(AuthorizationClient.java:645)
at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.onActivityResult(AuthorizationClient.java:142)
at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:134)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3023)
... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I ran into the same issue recently. If you update the facebook-android-sdk, this should be resolved. See the diff here:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/commit/ed74ff363e3a7c32b54567e68cc7e86ea27bdbd7#facebook/src/com/facebook/AuthorizationClient.java

specifically the null check added to line 619 in the file:

facebook/src/com/facebook/AuthorizationClient.java

Comment: I can't verify that it was reason right now. But it looks very like it is the problem. Thank You!